# How to pass data between pageFunction executions in Apify web

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, apify

I'm scraping website with Apify. I want to **scrape** different types of pages and then combine the data into one data set. Now i have different sets of data for each kind of pages (users, shots). How to transfer data between pageFunction executions, ex. to calculate followers number for each shot author.

```js
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { request, log, jQuery } = context;
    const $ = jQuery;
      
    if (request.url.indexOf('/shots/') > 0) {  
        const title = $('.shot-title').text();
        return {
            url: request.url,
            title
        };
    } else if (request.userData.label === "USER") {
        var followers_count = $('.followers .count').first().text();
        return {
            url: request.url,
            followers_count
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you can pass the data through crawled pages and save only one item in the end. For this use case, you can work with `userData`, which you can pass with every request.

For example, if you would like to pass the data from `/shots` site to the `USER`, you could do it like this. (but it requires you to enqueue pages manually to control the flow of the data, also this approach except that the /shots type of the page is the first one you visit and then continue)

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { request, log, jQuery } = context;
    const $ = jQuery;

    if (request.url.indexOf('/shots/') > 0) {  
        const title = $('.shot-title').text();

        const userLink = 'some valid url to user page'
        //add to the queue your request with the title in the userData
        await context.enqueueRequest({
            url: userLink,
            userData:{
                label:'USER',
                shotsTitle: title
            }
        })

    } else if (request.userData.label === "USER") {
        var followers_count = $('.followers .count').first().text();
        //here you need to get the shotsTitle and return it
        return {
            url: request.url,
            followers_count,
            shotsTitle: request.userData.shotsTitle
        };
    }
}
```

If you would need to share the between runs of the actors, that is other topic, let me know if it helped.

Also would recommend going through the getting started guide which is [here](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/guides/gettingstarted).